# Save the total sum in my table (codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

Newbie at codeigniter here. how can I save my total amount in my table per user? The only thing I did is to sum it and show it on my view. My target is to save the total commission on my **"agent_commission"** table". I have provided a screenshot of my target for better visualization. Thank you in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Views:

```
<?php $formattedNum = number_format($commCurrentBalance, 2);
                            echo $formattedNum;
                            ?
```

Controller:

```
public function commi()
    {
        $data['activeNav'] = "";
        $data['subnav'] = "commissions";
        $this->header($data);
        $this->nav();
        $data['currentPoints']=$this->session->userdata('currentPoints');
        $data['result'] = $this->commissions->get1();
        $data['commCurrentBalance']=$this->load->commissions->gettotalcommi(); //getting sum of amount
        $this->load->view('comm_view', $data);
        
        $this->footer();
    }
```

Model:

```
function gettotalcommi(){
        $reqcommi= $this->session->userdata('uid');
        
        $this->db->select_sum('amount');
        $this->db->where('commTo',$reqcommi);
        $result = $this->db->get('agent_commission_history')->row();
        
        return $result->amount;
    }
```

Comment: What is `$result->amount;` returning?

Comment: Hello, it is returning SUM of the column "amount".

Comment: Do you have a query that works outside of CI? I.e. in PhpMyAdmin/MySQL Workbench etc?

Comment: Are you trying to replicate something like this:: UPDATE agent_commission
SET commCurrentBalance = (
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM agent_commission_history
WHERE commTo = ?) 
WHERE commTo = ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to replicate it. Exactly on what you stated.

Comment: @Jake G
 `$data['commCurrentBalance']` this is the sum of total then you `insert` this value in column where you want.

Comment: rather than adding dynamic data to the table, use view and retrieve it from there.(view for **`agent_commission`**)

Comment: @Jake G  your problem is solved or not??

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much KUMAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will work but please try

```
$db->select_sum('amount');
$db->where('commTo',$param);
$aq = $db->get_compiled_select('agent_commission_history');

$db->set('commCurrentBalance',"($aq)",false);
$db->where('commTo',$param2);
$db->update('agent_commission');
```

This is the Codeigniter equivalent of the query I posted earlier:

```
UPDATE agent_commission 
SET commCurrentBalance = ( SELECT SUM(amount) FROM agent_commission_history WHERE commTo = ?) 
WHERE commTo = ?
```

Comment: Hello, this is the result of your suggestion.  https://prnt.sc/xsupt7 please see the screenshot thank you

Comment: Ah - sorry yes - you need a third "false" parameter on the set() command. See updated answer.

Comment: Sorry for 2 days late reply, I got an emergency. By the way. This is the result. Still error. https://prnt.sc/xyel17

Comment: It needs borders around it - please see revised script

Comment: It works. However, when there's no ID on agent_commission tbl, it is not updating. So what I'm doing is I need to insert manually before I can do update.https://prnt.sc/xyzdwa

Answer (score 1):

```
public function commi(){
 $data['commCurrentBalance']=$this->load->commissions->gettotalcommi(); //getting sum of amount
 
$dataArray = array(
        'commCurrentBalance'=>$data['commCurrentBalance']
        );
 
 $this->db->insert('agent_commission',$dataArray);
 
 $this->load->view('comm_view', $data);
        
        $this->footer();
    }
```